# Jenkins declarative pipeline - pass command arguments to docker run

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to pass parameters to the docker run entrypoint comand?
what i mean is, for the run command I need to have something like this:

```
docker run myImage --host.url.expected=http://url --host.url.actual=http://url
```

Currently the pipeline that I've build would look like:

```
agent {
 dockerfile {
 args '--host.url.expected=${params.EXPECTED} --host.url.actual=${params.ACTUAL}'
 }
}
```

but like this, will actually do something like:

```
docker run --host.url.expected=http://url --host.url.actual=http://url myImage
```

causing the script to fail of course

is there a way to achieve what I need?
Ideally still using a declarative pipeline... with as less boilerplate as possible

Let me know if you need more details, I can add the whole jenkinsfile / dockerfile if needed

Comment: Could you make host.url.expected and host.url.actual environment variables and have your command reading them, them then pass something like -args '-e -host_url_expected=http://url -e host_url_actual=http://url myImage'

Comment: works as a workaround, but is not what I am looking for